# Animation not working in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: animation, game-engine, export, import, unreal-engine

I'm very new to Blender and Unreal Engine. I'm trying to figure out why my Animations from Blender are not showing up in Unreal Engine 4. [Here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Alzgh9M2DzOsksMhJ9bzmwzqmWbQMg) is a file that I made for testing it out.

When I'm importing the file to Unreal Engine 4 this shows up

[image]

The Mesh is showing up in UE4

[image]

But the Animation is not showing

[image]

This is what the Output Log of Blender says

[image]

The Error "Imported bone transform is different from original. Please check Output Log to see detail of error." is the one that I can't get rit off.

This is probably a simple question but I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: "Please check Output Log to see detail of error." This is probably referring to the FBX exporter in Blender. Have you checked the log like it says? You can see output from the exporter by going to Window > Toggle System Console (and close it the same way - actually closing the window will close all of Blender)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the Output Log of Blender to my post.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I had a similar issue, this thread helped me fix it: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/736756/blender-animation-import-problem-empty-animations.html

If link dies the solution was,

> Turns out all I had to do was rename my character in blender from 'armature' to anything else.

Comment: this solution works, it's crazy but you can have your character named Armature when importing animations.

Comment: Still running into this issue on UE 5.2, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the animation problem, but the smoothing group error I can help with...

Export a Mesh from Blender
Geometry
Smoothing: Face or Edge (Not Normals Only)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, UE4 removes top bone if it is called "Armature". This workaround allow root motions to from root bone and not armature object.

If you intentionally keep the name "Armature" to use this workaround, you have to set UE4 "EnableRootMotion" to be true in animation Asset Details.

Then the model will be displayed in Unreal animation tab, while using the Armature name workaround.
[image: EnableRootMotion to true in Assets Details for animations]

There will also be an issue in Animation Blueprint, where the model dissappear. Set Anim Preview Editor "Root Motion Mode" to either use "Root Motion from Everything" or "Ignore Root Motion".

[image: Also need to configure Animation Blueprint and set Anim Preview Editor "Root Motion Mode" to either use "Root Motion from Everything" or "Ignore Root Motion"]

(There might be other issues, showing up elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

Rename Armature in blender in something else, Skeleton for example. It's seems like FBX UE importer issue, not sure.

Hope this will help to someone.